# Master Page is adding additional text in TextBox ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, master-pages

I have a master page which has a content section with the id cpMainContent. 
I am using this master page on every webform I am creating for college project. One of such form is frmSearchPersonnel. The purpose of frmSearchPersonnel is to ask user last name of the person they want to search in a textbox and then click on search button. The ID of TextBox is

```
        txtSearchName
```

Search button will do postbackUrl transfer to another form which I have named frmViewPersonnel. 
In frmViewPersonnel I am trying to use following code.

```
        NameValueCollection myRequest = Request.Form;
        if(!string.IsEmptyOrNull(myRequest["txtSearchName"]))
           string strSearch = myRequest["txtSearchName"];
```

The problem I ran into is that this didn't find any control with the name of txtSearchName. While debugging I found this in myRequest object,

```
                [5] "ctl00$cpMainContent$txtSearchName" string
```

Even though when I added textbox I gave it ID of txtSearchName but when page is rendered it is adding extra string from master page.

1. How can I stop this? I have to use master page so don't say not to use master page :)
2. Why is it doing that?

## Update

While Googling and Binging I found that I can use Control.ClientID in this case so looking into it.

## Update 2

As suggested below to add ClientIDMode="static" in the html of control or add it in page directive. What it does is, it keeps the ID static to txtSearchName but problem is this,

```
         <input name="ctl00$cpMainContent$txtSearchName" type="text" id="txtSearchName" />
```

Here name is still using ctl00 and the code I showed above,

```
            string strSearch = myRequest["txtSearchName"]
```

it still won't work because nvc collection is either searchable by index or name not the id directly.

==============
[image]

Comment: http://i1.asp.net/asp.net/images/master-pages/05/Images/aspnet_tutorial05_IDNaming_cs_figure04.png

Comment: http://www.asp.net/master-pages/tutorials/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-cs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are posting to another page that uses the same master page (called SiteMaster in my case), the name of the textbox should be same the same.

```
string val = Request[((SiteMaster)Master).txtSearchName.UniqueID];
```

If you're NOT posting to a page with the same master, well, then are you using the viewstate for the textbox at all since you're posting to another page? If not, just make the control a non asp.net control:

```
<input type="text" name="txtSearchName"/>
```

If you *are* using viewstate *and* posting to another page with a different master page, well, you should use PreviousPage.

Comment: I named my master page Frontend.Master and it is in Master Pages folder. When I try to cast like you have above it gives message name Frontend does not exist in this context.

Comment: You have about 5 coding errors in the sample you posted. Look at what I posted again. Ok. more like 3.

Try this:
strSearch = Request[((Frontend)Master).txtSearchName.UniqueID];

Comment: Only error I had was I was missing ] when I took this image which I added right after taking image and that was because I had to manually type it as intellisense was not picking any of it.

Comment: And your cast to Frontend is missing a closing parentheses in the right spot and you are missing a second opening parentheses in the right spot. And your second closing parentheses is in the wrong spot. Intellisense wasn't working because of the misplaced parens. P.s., I apologize if I'm coming off as rude; I think it's a function of the time. :)

Comment: +1 above. I have made it non asp.net control and then following code did it.  if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( Request[ "txtSearchName" ] ) )
                strSearch = Request[ "txtSearchName" ];   Thanks a bunch for help and patience, I am not dumb lol but it is just this time of the day here.

Answer (score 5):

1. You need to add a ClientIDMode="Static" to the html of the textbox:

> ```
> <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
> ```

1. It happens to prevent duplicate ID's. Usually it happens when you use master pages as it contains nested pages

If you want all controls with `ClientIDMode="Static"`, you can put it in the page header of the master file.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ClientIDMode="Static" %>
```

Comment: Well there is still issue with this approach, I will define it above in the question so it is clear. +1 though.

Comment: Oh right. I'm not sure if you can keep the name value the same. Regardless, with ASP.NET Webforms, you should avoid Request.Form as it defeats the purpose of Viewstate. Is there any reason why you're using Request.Form over directly accessing the textbox?

Comment: Well it is postback to other page. In that case I can also use PreviousPage and do it that way but I have to keep the code as dummify I can as I am lab lead in my class and if I go little left or right everyone gets totally confused in the lab .. they are already barely keeping up with the labs :) and lab was mentioning to use Request otherwise I woulda done PreviousPage

Answer (score 2):

Little late here. Appreciate `@aquinas` and `@rudeovski ze bear`. Interesting and good answers.

I'd same issue and I solved it differently.

In fact, I used a public Interface.

```
public interface ISearch
{
      string SearchText { get; }
}
```

Then implement `ISearch` interface in two aspx page say `One.aspx` and `Two.aspx` classes.

--One.aspx-- (Where I'v added TextBox1, and Button1 and set Button1.PostBackUrl="~/Two.aspx")

```
public partial class One : System.Web.UI.Page , ISearch 
{
    public    string SearchText
    {
        get
        {
            return TextBox1.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

--Two.aspx--

```
public partial class Two : System.Web.UI.Page, ISearch 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ISearch search = (ISearch)  PreviousPage;
        Label1.Text = search.SearchText;
    }
    public string SearchText
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes everyone goes through learning phase :) I hope I will get there and hanging in there

Answer (score 0):

If your try to access the input element value in code behind on post back instead of for example:

```
var emailAddress = Request.Form["ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentContainer$MainContent$MainContent$ContentBottom$ProfileFormView$emailaddress1"];
```

Use

```
  var emailAddressKeyName = Request.Form.AllKeys.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Contains("emailaddress1"));
        var emailAddress = Request.Form[emailAddressKeyName];
```